# R: Two graphs in one plot window below each other?

Tags: r, plot

I'm struggling with this..I have one xts series with multiple columns, each column representing stock data. Now I want to draw one graph at the top of a plot window and another below this one (not in the scale as the other). However with plot() and then lines() doesn't work...

My code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(BasketVariables)){
    plot(Basket[,2*i], main=colnames(Basket)[2*i])
    lines(Basket[,2*i+1], main=colnames(Basket)[2*i+1])
  }
```

Comment: See `?par`  for arguments `mfcol` and `mfrow`, and also function `?layout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that this is what you need

```
par(mfrow=2:1)
plot(1:5,5:1)
plot(1:5,5:1)
```